# Jupyter .ipynb file changes string format when read using nbformat package

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook

It's a super weird thing I got here, this is the cell content in a .ipynb

```
date = "2018-03-23"
day = "'{}'".format(date)
```

I am formating it because I want to enclose date string with single quotes,
but when i try to read this .ipynb file using

```
def read_ipynb_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        out = str(nbformat.read(file_path, as_version=4))
    return out
path = 'EDA.ipynb'
out = read_ipynb_file(path)
```

The out contains

```
{
        'cell_type': 'code',
        'execution_count': 50,
        'metadata': {},
        'outputs': [],
        'source': 'day = \'2018-03-23\''
}
```

How do I prevent those backslashes, as I have to validate this thing with below regex

```
range_day =  re.findall(r'day\s*=\s* \'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

And its throwing error due to those backslashes

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried things like making it a raw string, escaping the single quote, but it still add those backslashes in out.

Comment: Is `out` a string representation of this dictionary? I'm able to find the `range_day`. You can see the output here: https://ideone.com/SBdQZD

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Its not working on [link](https://regex101.com/)